# DDB schema for hot partitions usecase

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

**Usecase**
Application should support low latency with read after write consistency or minimal replication lag.
Item with Item_id can have multiple sub_items and minimum sub_items for each item_id are ~50000 and maximum are 1000000. Each sub_item will have some attributes (attr1, attr2).
Application has a feature where an item_id is only active for 3-4 days post which calls for that item_id are very rare

**Query patterns to be supported are**
Fetch all sub_items for an item_id
Fetch sub_items for an item_id matching some criteria i.e. attr1=='abc' or attr2==='efg'
Currently we have this usecase supported in Aurora MySQL but due to maintenance and performance issues we are planning to migrate to a NO-SQL DB like DDB.

For supporting above query patterns with DDB,

**schema #1**

hash_key - item_id

sort_key - sub_item_id

*Drawback*

#1 query pattern to return all sub_items for item_id, DDB has a throughput limitation of 3000 RCUs, so no parallelization beyond that can be done. Where as if we stick with Aurora MySQL I can make parallel batch calls with limit and offset which can make my querying faster.

***schema #2***

hash_key - item_id + sub_item_id

GSI - item_id

*Drawback*

To support #2 query pattern since we don't know sub_item_id we have to scan all the records in DDB which will be a costly operation. Or we can use GSI on item_id to query but even GSI have same throughput limitations of 3000 RCUs and 1000 WCUs

**Other alternate data stores evaluated**

AmazonDocument DB - Has same nuances as Aurora
MySQL w.r.t performance of DB optimizers and maintenance.

OpenSearch - Latency can be a concern if low refresh_interval is configured

**Suggestions needed on**

Is there a better schema in DDB which will address both the query patterns in a low latency manner?
Is there any alternate AWS datastore which will be better suitable for this usecase?

Comment: In once sentence you state you need up to 1M items, and in another you say items older than a couple of days aren't queried any longer? How many MB of data do you predict each request will return?

Comment: Applications usecase is that once an item is processed by all systems it is no longer actively needed. There can be some calls but are very rare. Regarding data size, each record size will be 1KB so if 1M records are present for an item, 1 Gb of data will be returned. I am also evaluating if we can add pagination to the API but offset pagination which can help in parallel processing at client side will not be possible. So thinking of ways in which i can increase parallel operations in system to minimize processing time for each item

Comment: Given the amount of data that you're retrieving in every query, a database seems like the wrong architecture. I would instead think of storing the data on S3 (assuming that you get it atomically), and using SQS to distribute work.

Comment: 1GB per request does not seem like a good use case for DynamoDB. DynamoDB will have to paginate for every 1MB of data. This article may help: https://medium.com/@leeroy.hannigan/optimizing-dynamodb-queries-using-key-sharding-f3eb4d7f78f7

Comment: If S3 is a suggested alternate #1 query pattern to selectively find subitems based on attributes will not be feasible. Are there any ideas to use both dynamo db and s3 together.  Actual data of each sub item is huge which i am storing in s3 and only storing required attributes to search in dynamo db. Are there any alternate solutions to support both query patterns using s3 and dynamo db ? One alternate is to store all data for an item in s3 and store attribute level information in open search to meet search criteria but latency and data consistency requirements will not be met

Comment: I read the article on sharding : https://medium.com/@leeroy.hannigan/optimizing-dynamodb-queries-using-key-sharding-f3eb4d7f78f7 but for my usecase, since size of data is not pre determined, how can know how many partitions to create ? also when querying how will we determine how many partitions to lookup for the data i.e hashkey#1 to hashkey#n how can we determine n ?